# Login functionality is not working in a web application using cypress

Tags: selenium-webdriver, cypress

I am trying to automate login functionality on a web application. The Username and Password fields are under Shadow DOM and I am using following code in cypress for this -

```
cy.get('#LoginUserName').shadow().find('#input').click({force: true}).focus().type('AdminUser', { force: true });
cy.get('#LoginPassword').shadow().find('#input').click({force: true}).focus().type('AdminPassword', { force: true });
cy.get('#LoginButton').click({ force: true })
```

When I run this code, I can see the values getting typed in the fields, but, after clicking on Login button, I see an error saying Username and Password values were not provided -
[image: Login Error]

Can someone please let me know how to resolve this?
Thanks in Advance..!!

**NOTE** - *When I try to automate this using Selenium WebDriver, I get **elementNotInteractable** exception while trying click or sendkeys methods on that username/password field*

Comment: Can you add the HTML for this?

Answer (score 0):

It may be that you just need to add `.trigger('change')` after the `.type()` commands.

If there's event handlers on the input fields, they may require this to fire the validation.

If the `.trigger('change')` event doesn't do it, try `.trigger('input')` and/or `.blur()`.
Which one works depends on how the events are set up.